# Asp.Net wcf vs ftp vs httphandler for file upload

Tags: silverlight, wcf, file-upload, ftp, httphandler

In my application i have to upload large files. Its a silverlight application which uploads the file using internet to some server. The application is installed on client machine. I was searching out for options that i can have. Any suggestion on which one would be better between WCF, FTP, Httphandler and why. I am using .Net 4.0 and save the file to Sql using SqlFileStream.

Comment: What is the client?? Browser or a custom app?

Comment: It a web application (internet) with browser as client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question really is: what problem are you trying to solve?

WCF is out of question since even if you get the browser to talk to a WCF service, it would have to be sitting on the top ASP.NET and doing what a simple ASP.NET page can.

Browser cannot upload FTP so that is out of question as well.

HttpHandler is an option but does not provide a benefit for uploads so you could use it but you might as well use a simple ASP.NET page.

Your main problems (and their solutions) are:

- ASP.NET is configured to accept up to 4 MB so you have to [change configuration](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx) to allow more.
- To get a reliable upload, you need to implement a **chunked uploading** at client side using Silverlight or Flash but you do not seem to be going that route.

---

### Update

Based on your updates, I would recommend chunked uploading using **SilverLight** on Client and **HttpHandler** on the server.

Comment: Hi, I have modified the question. It is a silverlight application